# What's wrong with Xsendfile in Yii

Tags: yii

I have been trying Xsendfile() method in Yii over 20 times and none of them gave me a result. Here is my code:

```
    $file_path = "D:/xampp/htdocs/mywebapp/protected/modules/file_upload".DS.
                  'views'.DS.'upload'.DS.testfile.".pdf"; 
    Yii::app()->request->xSendFile($file_path ,array(
       'saveName'=>$result['gen_name'] .".pdf",
       'mimeType'=>'application/pdf',
       'terminate'=>true,
     ));
```

And despite changing the location of testfile.pdf everywhere on my hard drive, none of them works. I am nearly exhausted with this method.
Anyone could help me from being headache? I am using windows and xampp 1.7.4.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Fyi, you can *always* use forward slashes (even on windows!) instead of some os-specific directory separator constant.

Answer (score 1):

Did u tune your server as needed to serve big files sending? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#xSendFile-detail

Comment: Hi Elkan!This file is not big not exceeds my php upload maximum file setting. Do you have another suggest for me? Thank you.

Comment: Hm.. stop at the moment, u are uploading or downloading file?O_o if downloading then just use CHttpRequest::sendFile(), it can serve big files normally too.

Comment: Yeah, I am downloading "pdf" file, and as I see sendFile() couldn't help me with pdf so I switched to use xSendFile().

Comment: Hm.. why it couldn't help u with pdf? ```$content = file_get_contents('mypdf.pdf'); Yii::app()->request->sendFile('mypdf.pdf',$content);``` is there anything that can be wrong to u? Please describe a little more of what u r trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Xsendfile only works if you have an Apache module installed on your web server. It isn't a normal option, so you probably don't. It'd be better to try the normal sendfile method or just write the file out yourself.

Comment: It is actually much better to use XSF if possible. It is much faster than any other way to send a file via PHP (except redirecting to it so the webserver serves the file directly)

Comment: Agreed.  I use it for a system of mine as well :-)  But if the original poster doesn't have the Apache module installed, it won't work at all.  With that in mind, the Yii sendFile method would work as well, although that particular method has to load the entire file into memory before sending it.  Hence my suggestion to just write the file out directly under certain circumstances.